# Rails devise delete register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, registration

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. But if i set up devise, how would i completely remove the ability of a user to signup. I could easily remove the signup views, but what else. Should i add something like devise_for :user, :except => register, or what? The reason im doing this, is because i want the database to be only seeded with users.

Comment: working on your routes, as you state, would be the best and easier way to proceed +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost right:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => :registrations
```

[Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3adevise_for).

Answer (score 3):

You should have on your models something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

To remove the signup, you should remove the registerable module, so you module should be like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :confirmable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: I am not able log in after remove :recoverable